# Simplifying code into one line in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, simplify

Here is my code:

```
Sub part1()
    Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
End Sub
```

I want to simplify it into 1 line so that it formats column A as integers. I know it's a very simple question but please help me.

Comment: `Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "0"`

Comment: Did you try simplifying your 2 lines to 1, by the link in the words select and selection?  I'd understand 3+ lines?

Comment: I guess i wasn't sure about whether the range had to be selected but I understand what you did. Thanks, sorry this was an incredibly simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub part1()

Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "0"

End Sub
```

**Selection** is not needed.